# Am I thinking correctly about this Bayes Problem

Tags: bayes

I am playing with the following problem.

> Recently a company has had some resignations. About **x** out of
>   **Total**  people resigned in one year. Some of the resignations were due to natural movement, new opportunities but also because  people
>   were negative. Lets say around **n** people that resigned were
>   negative. Using a questionnaire we can find out that currently around
>   **z** % of people are still negative

So the question is : What is the probability that someone that is negative will resign

I set it up like this:

```
           P(Negative|Resign) = P(Resign|Negative) * P(Negative) / P(Resign)
```

The above reads for me:

> The probability that someone that is currently negative will resign is
>   equal to the probability that when someone did resign in the past they
>   were negative times the probability that current employees from the
>   total is negative divided by the percentage total resignations.

from the above i want to get the answer by using these ratios in the formula

```
            P(Resigned|Negative) = n/x  

            P(Resigned) =   x/Total

            P(Negative) =  z
```

My questions:

1. Am I thinking about this correctly?
2. Am I applying the Bayes Theorem correctly
3. Would this actually give sensible answers

Comment: This can always qualify as an application of Bayes' theorem, but with no statistical implication. If n is a random output, it corresponds to an Hypergeometric(Total,x,z Total) model and you can use Bayesian statistics to infer about Total, x or z if any is unknown.

Comment: So assume then the answer to at least question 1 above is Yes. What do you mean 'without statistical implication'? n in this case is not a random output, but an input and we know the value.

Comment: If every parameter in the problem is known, then this is a pure probability problem and your answer is correct. But then what is the meaning of 'sensible' in question 3?